# How to solve this inequality correctly?

Tags: trigonometry, inequalities, resolve

Find the value range of real number a, so that for any real number x  and $\theta \in\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$,  make $(x+3+2 \sin \theta \cos \theta)^{2}+(x+a \sin \theta+a \cos \theta)^{2} \geqslant \frac{1}{8}$ constant.

```
ForAll[{θ, x}, 
 0 <= θ <= Pi/
  2, (x + 3 + 2 Sin[θ] Cos[θ])^2 + (x + 
     a*Sin[θ] + a*Cos[θ])^2 >= 1/8]
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

But the above code has been running, can not get the correct result. How to solve this problem correctly?

**Reference answer:**

[image]

Comment: This uses `Reduce[]` and not `Resolve[]`, but using the Weierstrass substitution (as always) goes a long way: `Simplify[Reduce[FullSimplify[TrigExpand[(x + 3 + 2 Sin[θ] Cos[θ])^2 + (x + a Sin[θ] + a Cos[θ])^2 >= 1/8 /. θ -> 2 ArcTan[t]]] && 0 < t < 1, {t, a, x}] /. t -> Tan[θ/2]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We set $y=\cos\theta$  and $z=\sin\theta$,then according to the conditions, $y^2+z^2==1$ and $y\geq 0, z\geq 0$.

And we consider the **inverse problem**,that is  `Exists` $x,y,z$ such that
$$(x + 3 + 2 zy)^2 + (x + az + ay)^2 \leq 1/8$$

## Method one

```
Maximize[{a, (x + 3 + 2 z*y)^2 + (x + a*z + a*y)^2 <= 1/8, y >= 0, 
  z >= 0, y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, y, z, a}]
```

> `7/2, {x -> -(13/4), y -> 0, z -> 1, a -> 7/2}}`

```
Minimize[{a, (x + 3 + 2 z*y)^2 + (x + a*z + a*y)^2 <= 1/8, y >= 0, 
  z >= 0, y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, y, z, a}]
```

> `{Sqrt[6], {..., a -> Sqrt[6]}}`

## Method two

```
Resolve[Exists[{x, y, 
   z}, {(x + 3 + 2 z*y)^2 + (x + a*z + a*y)^2 <1/8, y >= 0, z >= 0, 
   y^2 + z^2 == 1}], Reals]
```

> `Sqrt[6] < a < 7/2`

Comment: I see the inequality $$ (x+3+2 \sin \theta \cos \theta)^{2}+(x+a \sin \theta+a \cos \theta)^{2} \geqslant \frac{1}{8}$$ in the question under consideration, not $\le$.

Comment: @user64494 Note that  `Forall x,y,z, f(x,y,z)>=c` opposition  `Exist x,y,z, f(x,y,z)<c`

Comment: The inverse inequality is $$(x+3+2 \sin \theta \cos \theta)^{2}+(x+a \sin \theta+a \cos \theta)^{2}< \frac{1}{8} $$ and `Maximize[{a, (x + 3 + 2 z*y)^2 + (x + a*z + a*y)^2 < 1/8 && y >= 0 && 
   z >= 0 && y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, y, z, a}]` performs the message "Maximize::wksol: Warning: there is no maximum in the region in which the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; a result on the boundary will be returned."

Comment: You correctly found the bounds for `a`, but for the negation of the problem under consideration, not the  problem. This is not it.

Comment: @user64494 This means that  `a=7/2`  and `a=Sqrt[6]` can not attain at the negation problem,so it indicate that `Sqrt[6] < a < 7/2`

Answer (score 1):

According to `ForAll` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll.html), when you use multiple variables, you can't specify a satisfying condition, your `ForAll` code has one extra argument:

```
Resolve[ForAll[
  x, (x + 3 + 2 Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (x + 
        a*Sin[\[Theta]] + a*Cos[\[Theta]])^2 >= 1/8 && 
   0 <= \[Theta] <= Pi/2], Reals]
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: But the reference answer is $a \leq \sqrt{6}$ or $a \geq \frac{7}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Executing an equivalent form of your code

```
Reduce[ForAll[{x, \[Theta]}, (x + 3 + 
    2 Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (x + a*Sin[\[Theta]] + 
    a*Cos[\[Theta]])^2 >= 1/8 && \[Theta] >= 0 && \[Theta] <= 
Pi/2], a, Reals]
```

, one obtains

> ...Reduce:This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce

However, this can be done in two steps. First,

```
Reduce[ForAll[x, (x + 3 + 2 Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (x + 
     a*Sin[\[Theta]] + a*Cos[\[Theta]])^2 >= 1/8 && \[Theta] >= 
 0 && \[Theta] <= Pi/2], a, Reals] // Simplify
```

> `(\[Theta] >= 0 &&  2 \[Theta] < \[Pi] && (a <= (5 + 4 Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]])/( 2 (Cos[\[Theta]] + Sin[\[Theta]])) ||  a >= (7 + 4 Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]])/( 2 (Cos[\[Theta]] +  Sin[\[Theta]])))) || (2 \[Theta] == \[Pi] && (2 a <= 5 ||  2 a >= 7))`

produces the required bounds for concrete values of `\[Theta]`.

Second, one finds the bounds valid for all $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$ by

```
Minimize[{(5 + 4 Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]])/(2 (Cos[\[Theta]] + Sin[\[Theta]])), 
[Theta] >= 0 && \[Theta] <= Pi/2}, \[Theta]]
```

> `{(5 + 4 Cos[2 ArcTan[ Root[1 - 8 # + 2 #^2 + 8 #^3 + #^4& , 3, 0]]] Sin[2 ArcTan[ Root[1 - 8 # + 2 #^2 + 8 #^3 + #^4& , 3, 0]]])/(2 (Cos[2 ArcTan[ Root[1 - 8 # + 2 #^2 + 8 #^3 + #^4& , 3, 0]]] + Sin[2 ArcTan[ Root[1 - 8 # + 2 #^2 + 8 #^3 + #^4& , 3, 0]]])), {\[Theta] -> 2 ArcTan[ Root[1 - 8 # + 2 #^2 + 8 #^3 + #^4& , 3, 0]]}}`

which produces the upper bouds for `a` in terms of quadric and this can be expressed through radicals. To obtain numbers,

```
N[%]
```

> `{2.44949, {\[Theta] -> 0.261799}}`

The lower bound for `a` is simpler.

```
Maximize[{(7 + 4 Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]])/(2 (Cos[\[Theta]] + Sin[\[Theta]])), \
[Theta] >= 0 && \[Theta] <= Pi/2}, \[Theta]]
```

> `{7/2, {\[Theta] -> 0}}`

Therefore, since $2.44949 <5/2$, there is no bounds for `a` which are valid for all the $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but it's strange that  the reference answer is $a \leq \sqrt{6}$ or $a \geq \frac{7}{2}$.

Comment: @Alittlemouseonthepampas: I can say nothing, not seeing the solution which derives this answer.

Comment: @Alittlemouseonthepampas: Your "Reference answer" is unclear to me. Do you see math mistakes in my answer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you use the function `FullSimplify` for simplification, `a` is $\sqrt{6}$.